# Sum of $50$ terms of $\cot^{-1}3+\cot^{-1}7+\cot^{-1}13+\cot^{-1}21+.....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inverse-function

> Find the sum of the first $50$ terms of the series $$\cot^{-1}3+\cot^{-1}7+\cot^{-1}13+\cot^{-1}21+.....$$

$$
\sum_1^{50}=\cot^{-1}3+\cot^{-1}7+\cot^{-1}13+\cot^{-1}21+.....\\
=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{7}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{13}+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{21}+.....=
$$
My reference gives the solution $\tan^{-1}\dfrac{5}{6}$, but I do not have any clue of doing it ?

**Note:** I know that $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}$ if $xy<1$.

Comment: Note that $$\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$

Comment: what function is the sequence $3,7,13,21,...$ given by? How are we supposed to find the series if we don't know how to write it in $\sum$ notation?

Comment: @clathratus, I assume $a_1=3, a_n=a_{n-1}+2n$.

Comment: $a_n=1+n+n^2$, I guess

Comment: Find the sum of the first $M$ terms, for $M=1,2,3,4,5$  Look for a formula that works for those, and use induction to prove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint

- Use the fact that $\cot^{-1}(x)=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$
- $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{(n+1)-n}{1+n(n+1)}\right) =\tan^{-1}(n+1) -\tan^{-1}(n)$